# How to split a sum into its parts without converting to string in python

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I have some expression

```
from sympy import *
a,b,c,x,y = symbols('a c b x y') 
eq=a*x + b*x*y + c*y**2
```

that needs to be split into an array containing the monomials.

The current solution I have is

```
parts = str(eq).split(' + ')
```

Then, I use the eval function on each element of the array parts to be interpreted as an expression.

What could I do to split the multivariate polynomial into the monomial parts without first converting the expression to a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [explore a `sympy` expression using `.func` and `.args`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#recursing-through-an-expression-tree):

```
eq.func
> <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
eq.args
> (a*x, b*y**2, c*x*y)
```

Each of these args are again `sympy` expressions and can be explored in the same way:

```
eq.args[0].func
> <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'
eq.args[0].args
> (a, x)
```

And so on. Note that at the final levels of the expression tree you will need other functions than `.func` and `.args`, for example:

```
eq.args[0].args[0].name  # the a in a*x
> 'a'
eq.args[1].args[1].args[1].n()  # the 2 in y**2
> 2.00000000000000
```