# how to divide a formula in its terms in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to this with other formulas as well.

```
    input = "3x+7-2x"
    # output = ["3x", "+7", "-2x"]
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[['3', 'x'], '+', '7'], '-', ['2', 'y']]`?, so pairing left and right operands with an operator, and the multiplication operators implied?

Comment: [sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126448/how-to-split-a-sum-into-its-parts-without-converting-to-string-in-python) maybe.

Comment: Do you mean *terms*? https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(mathematics)

Comment: yes i mean terms

Comment: are you looking for something like this output?? ["3x", "+", "7", "-", "2y"]

Comment: I need to know that 2y is negative, bc I have to calculate with it

Comment: Check out http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single regular expression and `findall`:

```
import re
input_str = "3x+7-2x"
output = re.findall(r"[-+]?[^-+]+",input_str)
output
```

which results in:

```
>>> ['3x', '+7', '-2x']
```

To generalize splitting on more operators:

```
output = re.findall(r"[-+/*]?[^-+/*]+",input_str)
```

(make sure the `-` is either at the start or end of its inner regex character class, as it has another meaning when it's not).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
output = input.replace('-',' -').replace('+',' +').split()
```

You shoud get:

```
['3x', '+7', '-2x']
```

Comment: appreciate the technique, hence the upvote. But solution cannot handle all situations like `3x + 7 - 2x`

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this.

First you specify a list of operators:

```
operators = {"+", "-", "*", "/"}
```

Then you iterate thorough the input like this:

```
result = []
tmp = ""
for char in input_str:
    if char in operators:
        result.append([tmp])
        tmp = ""
    tmp += char
result.append([tmp])
```

Comment: and you should not use input as variable name. its a builtin function

Answer (score 0):

For output like output = ["3x", "+", "7", "-", "2x"], here is the solution:

```
input = "3x+7-2x"
op=re.split("([+-/*])", input.replace(" ", ""))
```

For your output = ["3x", "+7", "-2x"], here is the solution:

```
import re


input = "3x+7-2x"
op = re.split("([+-/*])", input.replace(" ", ""))
oup=[]
skip = False
for ind, val in enumerate(op):
    if val in ['+','-','*','/']:
        oup.append(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, op[ind:ind+2]))
        skip = True
    else:
        if not skip:
            oup.append(val)
        else:
            skip=False
print oup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
input = "3x+7-2x"
parsed = re.findall('[-\+]*\d[a-zA-Z]*', input)
```

Output:

```
['3x', '+7', '-2x']
```